# Should tablevalued parameters in TSQL have database constraints?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server has table valued parameters that help in encapsulating multiple values of an entity into single type. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Assume that CRUD APIs use this type to trigger different stored procedures. Should the checks on mandatory values (like field X is required while creation) be added to create_stored_procedure or these must be added as constraints like 'NOT NULL' to table type.

What is the suggestion or best practice from maintainability perspective ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends... The whole purpose of any constraint is to control the the data being inserted... Adding constraints to your TVPs will help insure that you are getting only valid values. Of course that means invalid values will generate errors. So, the question becomes, where and how do you want to handle invalid values?

As a general rule, I create my TVP tables, the same way I create any other table... All columns have a datatype that is appropriate for the data being captured and set to NOT NULL unless there is a specific reason to leave it NULLable.

Comment: But the problem around is that - Entity E may have 6 fields and 4 of them are mandatory while creation, but only one is mandatory while updation. How would I use same TVP in create and update API ? Wouldn't it make more sense to check the required fields and availability in API layer or inside stored procedure as if statement - while keeping TVPs open ended. What's your opinion

Comment: @Illuminati - Something sounds a bit off if you have 3 data points in your object that are readonly once they are created. That has the sound of something not being done correctly. But that sounds like maybe you would have the one column be not nullable.